# #1109 - Unknown table 'master_benang' in field list

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

```
BEGIN
            IF (master_benang.jenis_benang = NEW.jenis_benang && NEW.LOT = master_benang.LOT) 
            THEN
            UPDATE master_benang 
            SET BOX_KRG= BOX_KRG + NEW.BOX_KRG,
             KG= KG + NEW.KG,
             BALE= BALE + NEW.BALE
             WHERE jenis_benang = NEW.jenis_benang && LOT = NEW.LOT ;
            ELSE
            INSERT INTO master_benang (id_supplier, jenis_benang, tipe_benang, LOT, BOX_KRG, KG, BALE, keterangan)
            VALUES(NEW.id_supplier, NEW.jenis_benang, NEW.tipe_benang, NEW.LOT, NEW.BOX_KRG, NEW.KG, NEW.BALE, NEW.keterangan);
             END IF;
            END
```

I tried the trigger above and it doesn't have any problem when I run it but when I insert data in the table which has the trigger the code doesn't work and shows an error
#1109 - Unknown table 'master_benang' in field list

Comment: Please add create trigger statement , in fact add all trigger code if feasible..

Comment: Mysql does not get this wrong error code is correct. show tables to check..